# What is different that Httpparams set function call directlry or after cemicolmn

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I use httpparams in angular 6. and i have one question.

when i use Httpparams with set, it is very difference that `set` funciton called after Constructor or called variable name.

```
funtionTest(): any{
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
            .set('one','one')
            .set('two','two')
            .set('thr','thr');
    ... some request
}

funtionTest2(): any{
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params.set('one','one');
    params.set('two','two');
    params.set('thr','thr');
    ... some request
}
```

if i called `functionTest()`, that `one` `two` `thr` describe of querystring

ex) `requestUrl?one=one&two=two&thr=thr`;

but, if i called `functionTest2()`, any information not shown. i think that one ~ thr querystring is inserted body.

what was difference that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpParams are **immutable** : it means you don't modify it, but rather return a new object everytime.

The first function could be translated to

```
funtionTest(): any{
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('one','one');
    params = params.set('two','two');
    params = params.set('three','three');
    ...
}
```

That's why your second function doesn't work : you don't assign the return value to anything.

To know that, simply check the signature of the `set` function with a Ctrl + Click !